# Networkx & Jupyter Notebook using pip AttributeError

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, networkx

> Hi everyone, I'm trying to create a network visualization with python using the networkx package. Unfortunately I'm getting a "AttributeError: module 'scipy.sparse' has no attribute 'coo_array'" at the end of my code. I've tried to fix it but every help in the internet points towards upgrading pip or conda which I've done and still get the same error. I'm using jupyter notebooks - any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Prerequisites

import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user networkx
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user numpy
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user pandas
```

```
pip install notebook --upgrade
```

```
conda upgrade notebook
```

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pathlib import Path
from pandas import DataFrame

#Read in Source File - NB this must match the schema requirements

df_InputData = pd.read_excel("/Users/paulkruse/Desktop/FR/Fr1.xlsx")
Src_Column = 'Source ID'
Tgt_Column = 'Target ID'

print(df_InputData);

#Nodes are positioned using the Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm.

Q = nx.Graph()
arr_SrcTgt= np.array(df_InputData[[Src_Column, Tgt_Column]])

print(arr_SrcTgt);

Q.add_edges_from(arr_SrcTgt)

dict_Coords = nx.spring_layout(Q)
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv6ko.png]

Comment: Why is [tag:anaconda] tagged? Conda users are not recommended to install into user site (`pip install --user`). See [Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `scipy` version is out of date. The most recent version `1.8.1` certainly has [coo_array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_array.html) function. One way to resolve this should be to upgrade scipy. If you're doing this from inside jupyter notebook, then use

```py
!pip install --user scipy==1.8.1
```

Make sure to restart kernel after installation.

Comment: Thanks, used the pip install and  it worked!